# Maven WAR: split classes JAR for different packages

Tags: java, maven, war

I'm developing J2EE web apps with Eclipse (using m2e plugin). If my project contains some classes dedicated to a specific customer, usually I group them to a specific package, like:

- com.myapp.logic
- com.myapp.logic.customer1
- com.myapp.logic.customer2

so at deploy time I can package them to different JARs using the Eclipse .jardesc descriptors, obtaining something like:

- myapp.jar
- myapp-customer1.jar
- myapp-customer2.jar

The advantage of this approach is that if I need to update only customer1 classes I can update only customer1 jar (if dependencies are not changed).

Now I would like to use Maven in my webapp projects but I can't find a solution to keep jars separated.
Using WAR plugin with `archiveClasses` configuration I can deploy only one JAR for my classes and I can't configure how to split packages into different JARs.

I've considered to use overlays but the entire project must be splitted into several projects and may become too complex (especially if I have 20/30 customers). I would prefer only a "lighter" split for classes deployment.

Alternatively, is there a way with Maven to package my classes into different JARs before WAR assembly (using different `executions`) and then include them into WAR ignoring standard deploy of classes (or equivalent JAR) ?

Comment: I think this use case is not for Maven. You have to use Gradle instead.

Comment: Using Maven you would create a module containing your shared logic (`com.myapp.logic`) and a module for each customer logic and than have multiple modules to produce the different war files.

Comment: @hotzst yes, is the overlay approach mentioned in the question

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Maven, would be better to create a multi module project if you want to separate code in different jars.

So you would have :

1. One parent pom (packaging pom)
2. One or more utility jar (packaging jar)
3. One war to pack the application (packaging war)

Here is a full example (that actually build an EAR but you can skip the EAR if you don't need) :

https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/multi-module-project-eclipse/

If you need to separate for customers you could do that with maven profiles:

```
    <profile>
        <id>customer2</id>
        <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
                <artifactId>artificatCustomer2</artifactId>
            </dependency>        


    <profile>
        <id>customer1</id>
        <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
                <artifactId>artificatCustomer1</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. However, as mentioned in original question: 
`I've considered to use overlays but the entire project must be splitted into several projects and may become too complex (especially if I have 20/30 customers). I would prefer only a "lighter" split for classes deployment`

Comment: @DamianoZucconi have you considered to use modules and manage the aggregation with maven profiles or repository branching? (Both solutions are ok, especially if the customers have not full access to source repositories)

Comment: I've considered Maven profiles but can I split JAR created with WAR plugin using profiles ? I see that you can split jars using JAR plugin with profiles but not with WAR plugin (where I only have archiveClasses option). Actually I would like to use modules and overlays but I have 65 customers packages now and so I would need to create 65 different modules

Comment: @DamianoZucconi well, you  need anyway to create 65 different configurations of some kind, no matter which method you use.